# How to upload web cam video directly to red5 server using flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5

I can access my web cam using flash. How can I upload that video stream to the red5 media server using flash and action script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial about setting up Red5 and there's a sample AS3 application included showing a simple streaming application.

You can find it here: http://labs.distriqt.com/post/493

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you deploy the streaming application? I downloaded the zip file. Then I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: The streaming application should just be a swf file? I.e. a flash application and you should be able to embed that in a web page like normal. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

See the demo applications: https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fjava%2Fexample%2Ftrunk for example the oflaDemo how to code a Flash Client based on the examples given.